# Display issue : black and white icons

Tags: display, icons

I have a display issue on my Ubuntu, my terminal has turned white, and my icons are in black and white. How can I revert it to the original version?

[image]

Comment: Changing your desktop theme should fix it if you think it needs fixing.

Comment: No I tried, my theme is set to yaru (my original theme) but this what is displayed. I thought it was beacause I went to the recovery mode once without doing on purpose but when I went back to the normal boot it still have these weird icons.